# VScode could not connect to docker container

Tags: docker, vscode-debugger, wsl-2

I try to attach my VScode into my running docker container but error occurs.
Here is error info from terminal:

```
[169 ms] Dev Containers 0.327.0 in VS Code 1.86.2 (903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda).
[168 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[172 ms] Setting up container: /it5007-2220
[312 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container /it5007-2220
[805 ms] Start: Run: wsl -l -v
[1168 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d docker-desktop-data -e /bin/sh -c echo ~
[1652 ms] Could not connect to WSL.
[1653 ms] Command failed: wsl -d docker-desktop-data -e /bin/sh -c echo ~
[1653 ms] 
[1653 ms] <3>WSL (20) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:708: Failed to translate D:\Microsoft VS Code
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:754: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\vmWare\bin\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\system32
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\Java\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\Java\jre\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\nodeJs\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\mysql-8.0.31-winx64\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\Git\cmd
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\xshell\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\xftp\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\xmanager\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\Redis-x64-3.2.100
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate E:\develop\elasticsearch-7.17.1\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\Python\Scripts\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\Python\
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Users\15311\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2\bin
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: UtilTranslatePathList:2866: Failed to translate C:\Users\15311\AppData\Roaming\npm
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:331: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (20) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return
[1657 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[1657 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[2232 ms] Server API version: 1.43
[2235 ms] Start: Run: D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\15311\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.327.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js set-up --container-id df4692579660b134d0a3356e2985a484db3f412af1170be12e8b88ef61b4fa3d --user-data-folder c:\Users\15311\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-33f54618-5ab8-46fe-81cb-64710a35f44d1709101994077 --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\15311\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\imageConfigs\it5007_tutorial%3at4.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --skip-post-create
[2324 ms] D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe: bad option: --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node
[2341 ms] Exit code 9
[2349 ms] Command failed: D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\15311\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.327.0\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js set-up --container-id df4692579660b134d0a3356e2985a484db3f412af1170be12e8b88ef61b4fa3d --user-data-folder c:\Users\15311\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-33f54618-5ab8-46fe-81cb-64710a35f44d1709101994077 --log-level debug --log-format json --config c:\Users\15311\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\imageConfigs\it5007_tutorial%3at4.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --skip-post-create
[2349 ms] Exit code 9
```

My docker container runs normally, I hope to fix it so that I can code inside the container.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  If this is specifically about VSCode integration then it's possible a screen shot of your IDE could be the best way to communicate what's being set up, but please make sure to include that inline and not behind a link.  In any case you should be able to [edit] your question to include details like the `docker-compose.yml` file or the URL you're trying to connect to in plain text.

Comment: thx for remind, have edited